# неправильные разделители при выгрузке в CSV

Tags: c#, csv, export

При попытке выгрузить обьекты с помощью библиотеки using Jitbit.Utils.CSVexport данные выгружаются неправильно, разделитель - табуляция, вместо запятой.

выгружаю так:

```
   bool result = export.ExportToFile(MakePath(Work_with_massive.GlobalPath) + MakeName(Work_with_massive.GlobalPath) + " WIX.csv", 8);
```

Т.е. дефолтным методом библиотеки, думаю ну косяк в самом методе ( кстати не первый раз уже дорабатываю метод выгрузки в либе) 
Полез в метод:

```
public bool ExportToFile(string path, int encodingType)
    {
        bool result = false;



        if (encodingType == 8)
            try { File.WriteAllLines(path, ExportToLines(), Encoding.UTF8);
                result = true;
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if(ex is IOException || ex is UnauthorizedAccessException)
                MessageBox.Show("Приложение обработало исключение (Нет доступа к целевой папке. Запись не удалась" );
                result = false;
            }
        if (encodingType == 32)
            try { File.WriteAllLines(path, ExportToLines(), Encoding.UTF32);
                result = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (ex is IOException || ex is UnauthorizedAccessException)
                    MessageBox.Show("Приложение обработало исключение (Нет доступа к целевой папке. Запись не удалась");
                result = false;
            }
        return result;
    }
```

Вижу что юзается то, что переписать я уже никак не смогу

```
File.WriteAllLines
```

Который в свою очередь вызывает:

```
ExportToLines()
```

Который в свою очередь вызывает:

```
private IEnumerable<string> ExportToLines()
    {
        if (_includeColumnSeparatorDefinitionPreamble) yield return "sep=" + _columnSeparator;

        // The header
        yield return string.Join(_columnSeparator, _fields.Select(f => MakeValueCsvFriendly(f, _columnSeparator)));

        // The rows
        foreach (Dictionary<string, object> row in _rows)
        {
            foreach (string k in _fields.Where(f => !row.ContainsKey(f)))
            {
                row[k] = null;
            }
            yield return string.Join(_columnSeparator, _fields.Select(field => MakeValueCsvFriendly(row[field], _columnSeparator)));
        }
    }
```

Я так понимаю проблема где то здесь, в этом блоке, вообще непонятно почему метод не принимает параметр установки сепаратора, а выдумывает его сам, но не могу понять что и где изменить чтобы выгружаемые данные использовали в качестве разделителя запятую а не знак табуляции...

Comment: Похоже, что вам с этим не на so надо, а к автору библиотеки. Если есть код на гитхабе - попробуйте сделать пулл-риквест.

Comment: спасибо, так и сделаю! Покопался и понял что самому мне ее не победить..

Comment: А как вы создаете сам объект Jitbit.Utils.CSVexport? На Gitgub в тексте самого класса есть перегруженный конструктор: public CsvExport(string columnSeparator=",", bool includeColumnSeparatorDefinitionPreamble=true), где и устанвливаются значения разделителя

Comment: вы абсолютно правы, так все и есть, есть конструктор, задавай разделитель как хочешь, но он уже по дефолту - запятая, либо у меня глюки либо я даже не знаю. Вот смотрите два файла - один (как должно быть) второй (как выгружает у меня) 

Первый (Шаблон):
https://is.gd/VeGQjO
второй:
https://is.gd/dVkamA


Если это два идентичных по структуре CSV файла, значит пора лечиться.
если нет, значит библиотека все таки косячит  и неправильно ставит разделитель.